# ASP.NET MVC 5 - How can I combine two input to one record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

If my model have a "Name" column is required, my view have "First Name" and "Last Name" two Input.

So should I use `@Html.Textbox` and give different id or should I use `@Html.TextboxFor`?

After I click submit, how can I combine two input text save to my `Name` column?

Comment: Please post the code you have so far

Comment: create FirstName and LastName model Properties along with Name property. Use FirstName and LastName in TextboxFor of both inputs . Then combine the names in controller post action and then assign it to your Name property.

Comment: Rather than adding properties to the model, I would create a view model with FirstName and LastName fields.  Then in the post you can combine those however you want into the entity before saving the record.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of what you could do- adding a read only property for full name while keeping your existing model properties for first name and last name.

```
  public class NameViewModel
  {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
      get
      {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
      }
    }
  }
```

Now in you're controller action, you will immediately be able to call `myViewModel.FullName` and retrieve the full name and it will be formatted however you want (my example has it formatted as "firstName lastName")

Comment: @ChrisWang Please upvote and accept the answer if this helped you